# Tengo una impresión de PDF por Core 6 C# usando Aspose sin embargo salen dos archivos PDF uno por una impresora y otro por otra

Tags: c#, pdf, impresion

espero me puedan ayudar, tengo un problema al imprimir un PDF que lo mando por una impresora en especifico y me sale un archivo de PDF con un peso en byte bajo, y luego dos segundos más tarde por otra me sale el archivo por otra que no tiene nada que ver con esta, cabe destacar que las impresoras están instaladas en el servidor donde están varias páginas. Mas abajo le dejo la captura de las impresoras y el código que es bastante básico. Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

´´

```
System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings ps = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings pgs = new System.Drawing.Printing.PageSettings();
ps.PrinterName = "PRINT01";
pgs.PaperSize = new System.Drawing.Printing.PaperSize();
pgs.Margins = new System.Drawing.Printing.Margins();
PdfViewer viewer = new PdfViewer();
viewer.BindPdf(@"wwwroot\\UserFile\\" + archivo + fecha + ".pdf");
viewer.PrintDocumentWithSettings(pgs, ps);
viewer.PrintDocument();
viewer.Close();
```

Comment: te aseguraste de tener la impresora deseada como predeterminada???, puede que por ahí este la solución.

Comment: Sí, estuve probando con esa variante también, sin embargo el tema va al parecer que la impresora es una Zebra y aparentemente manda unos caracteres de control que sería ese archivo que envía menos pesado, sin embargo va en mi maquina lo envía a la misma impresora y en el servidor es donde lo envía a diferentes.